# ActionExecutingContext - ActionParameters vs RouteData

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing, action-filter

Given the following code:

```
public class MyActionFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        var a = filterContext.ActionParameters["someKey"];
        var b = filterContext.RouteData.Values["someKey"];          
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

What is the difference between `a` and `b` ?

When should we be using action parameters over route data? What is the difference?

Comment: where is @DarinDimitrov when you need him. :)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

When you use `ActionParameters` on `OnActionExecuting`, you can change the values that are sending by the client-side before processing an action, for sample:

```
public class MyActionFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        filterContext.ActionParameters["customerId"] = 852;

        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

If you have an action using a customerId parameter, you will get the value setted on the action filter, since your action has the filter, for sample:

When you request any url like this: `/customer/detail/123`, you will get `852` value on CustomerId:

```
[MyAction]
public ActionResult Detail(int customerId)
{
   // customerId is 852

   return View();
}
```

`RouteData` is just about the values are on the url, processing by route tables.